# How can we find the line?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the line that passes through $(3,1,-2)$ and intersects at a right angle the line $x=-1+t, y=-2+t, z=-1+t$.

The line that passes through $(3,1,-2)$ is of the form $l(t)=(3,1,-2)+ \lambda u, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ where $u$ is a parallel vector to the line.

There will be a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $3+ \lambda u_1=-1+t, 1+ \lambda u_2=-2+t, -2+ \lambda u_3=-1+t$.

Is it right so far? How can we continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you're given is

$$(-1,-2,1)+t(1,1,1)$$

Thus, as you said, you want a line $\;(3,1,-2)+\lambda u\;$ , with $\;u\perp(1,1,1)\;$ , so if $\;u=(a,b,c)\;$ , you need

$$u\cdot(1,1,1)=a+b+c=0$$

From here it is easier, I beleive.

Comment: Why should it hold $\;u\perp(1,1,1)\;$ ?

Comment: @Evinda, that is what you wrote: you want the line you construct to be orthogonal or perpendicular (at a right angle) to the given one.

Comment: So saying that a line intersects at a right angle an other line, means that the lines are perpendicular, right? $$$$
Is $a+ \lambda b$ perpendicular to $d+t c$ iff $\lambda \cdot t=0$ ?

Comment: Or does it have to hold $b \cdot c=0$ ?

Comment: @evinda The direction vectors must be perpendicular, so it must be $\;b\cdot c=0\;$ , if $\;b\,,\,\,c\,$ are the vectors and $\;\lambda\,,\,\,t\;$ are the real parameters.

Comment: So the parallel points of the lines have to be perpendicular, right?

Comment: @Evinda I'm not sure I understand your question: what "parallel points of the lines"?

Comment: A line is of the form $a+t u$ , where $u$ is parallel to the line. That's what I meant. Is this right?

Comment: Also do we say that the line is of the form $(3,1,-2)+ \lambda (a,b,c)$ where $a+b+c=0$ or do we use the latter equality do express $(3,1,-2)+ \lambda (a,b,c)$ elsewhise?

Comment: @Evinda You may want to solve $\;a+b+c=0\;$ , for example $\;a=1=-b\;,\;\;c=0\;$ , or just state the general form. I can't tell, it depends on your teacher's requirements.

Comment: So can we set as $a,b,c$ any number that we want, we just have to take into consideration the equality $a+b+c=0$, right?

Comment: @Evinda Yes, correct.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Equation of line passing through $(3,1,-2)$ is given by $$\frac{x-3}{l}=\frac{y-1}{m}=\frac{z+2}{n}.$$This line is perpendicular to the line $\displaystyle \frac{x+1}{1}=\frac{y+2}{1}=\frac{z+1}{1}$.

Comment: Why is the first line perpendicular to the second one?

Answer (score 1):

A normal vector to the plane passing through $A(3,1,-2)$ perpendicular to the given line is the directing vector $(1,1,1)$ of this line. If it passes through the point $(3,1,-2)$, a cartesian equation of the plane is thus:
$$x+y+z=3+1-2=2.$$
It intersects the line at the point  $B(t-1,t-2,t-1)$ which satisfies this equation, i.e. $3t-4=2$, whence $t=2$. Thus the sought for line has directing vector $\overrightarrow{BA} (2,1,-3) $ and a parametric representation of this line is, vectorially, $M=A+u\,\overrightarrow{BA} $, i.e.
$$x=3+2u,\enspace y=1+u,\enspace z=-2-3u.$$

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: It is simply a way of rewriting the vector equation $\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot \overrightarrow{u}=0$, where $A$ is the point $(3,1,-2)$, $M$ is the point $(x,y,z)$  and $\overrightarrow{u}$ the directing vector of the other line.

Comment: @Bernard I think the equation you wrote is a plane's, not a straight line's.

Comment: It's a plane but it's a useful step. The desired line is in that plane. Also, the given line intersects the plane somewhere, and the desired line must pass through the given point and that intersection point.

Comment: @David, Thank you. I'm just not sure what Bernard meant with "cartesian form" for a line in three dimensional space. It seems, and perhaps the asker could deduce, that the above is the equation of the sought line, and it really isn't.

Comment: Thank you @DavidK, perhaps that was the intention of the writer though I didn't understand it that way.

Comment: @Joanpemo I rather think it was a mistake on their part. But you seem to have this well under control.

Comment: @Joanpem: You're right. I was thinking of a problem in the plane, while calculating with $3$ coordinates. As an excuse, I was doing two things at a time. I'll update my answer in a moment

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much.